# Consuming Laravel's internal API gets an 'Unauthenticated' error

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a problem while consuming the laravel internal APIs, when i try to call the API then i get the error "Unauthenticated" but when i try in the postman and it works.

**Here's my code:**

```
$req = Request::create('api/user', 'GET');
$req->headers->set('accept', 'application/json');
$req->headers->set('content-type', 'application/json');
$req->headers->set('authorization', 'Bearer [mytoken]');
$res = Route::dispatch($req)->getContent();
return ($res);
```

**Output**

```
{"error":"Unauthenticated."}
```

**I've tried**

Added the following code to the `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

Is there something missing?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you have a case problem:

> ```
> $req->headers->set('authorization', 'Bearer [mytoken]');
> ```

but

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
> ```

So I would change it like this:

```
$req->headers->set('Authorization', 'Bearer [mytoken]');
```

and the RewriteRule can be simplified:

```
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

If this also do not work please provide some log files.

Comment: Thank you for reply but still no change

Comment: Please do a  debug log for your request and share it